# usage: cc [ options] files. Use 'cc -flags' for details

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile. When I run it on Unix I get this error:

```
cc -I/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/rdbms/demo -I/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/rdbms/public \
   -I/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/plsql/public \
   -I/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/network/public -I../common -I../include -I. \
   -L/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/lib -L/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/rdbms/lib -L../../lib \
   -g -errwarn=%all -Xt  -lclntsh -ldl -Bstatic -lclient9 -lvsn9 -lcommon9 -lgeneric9 \
   -lmm -lcore9 -lnls9  -lwssmbx -ldes -lnsl -lsocket -lgen -lm -o bessToWss

usage: cc [ options] files.  Use 'cc -flags' for details  
*** Error code 1
```

What does "`usage: cc [ options] files. Use 'cc -flags' for details`" mean?

I'm not sure why I get the error because I do use `cc -flags`:

```
$(TARGET_DIR)/bessToWss: $(INTFOBJS)  
    cc $(CFLAGS) $(INTFOBJS) $(OCISHAREDLIBS) -o $@
```

**EDIT: Adding my entire makefile**

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0

COMMON_SRC=../common
BNS_INCLUDE=../include
LIBHOME=$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib/
RDBMSLIB=$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/lib/

WSSLIBS     =-lwssmbx -ldes
LLIBRDBMS_CLT   =-lclient9 -lvsn9 -lcommon9 -lgeneric9 -lmm
LLIBCLNTSH      =-lclntsh -ldl
CORELIBS        =-lcore9 -lnls9 
LDLIBS          =-lnsl -lsocket -lgen -lm
EXSYSLIBS       =-R $(ORACLE_HOME)/lib

STATICTTLIBS    =$(LLIBRDBMS_CLT) $(CORELIBS) $(WSSLIBS) $(LDLIBS)
OCISHAREDLIBS   =$(LLIBCLNTSH) -Bstatic $(STATICTTLIBS)


LDFLAGS     =-L$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib -L$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/lib -L../../lib

INCLUDE     =-I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/demo -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/public -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/plsql/public -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/network/public -I$(COMMON_SRC) -I$(BNS_INCLUDE) -I. 

CFLAGS      =$(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) -g -errwarn=%all -Xt

BESSOBJS=bessToWss.o


COMMONLIST=$(COMMON_SRC)/oracle.c \
    $(COMMON_SRC)/logger.c

INTFOBJS=$(BESSOBJS) $(COMMONLIST)


$(TARGET_DIR)/bessToWss: $(INTFOBJS)
    cc $(CFLAGS) $(INTFOBJS) $(OCISHAREDLIBS) -o $@
clean:
    $(RM) *.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you have an invalid compiler option on the command line.  It might be that you are using the 'wrong' compiler (maybe GCC instead of Sun's compiler, for example).  The probable problem options I see are:

- `-Xt`
- `-errwarn=%all`

and maybe (but probably not)

- `-Bstatic`

The others would not lead to usage errors like that.

*(NB: It would help to identify the machine and the compiler you are using, and the compiler Oracle expects you to use.)*

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have any object files to actually link together. The $(INTFOBJS) variable is likely empty. Along with potentially having the wrong flags, this would also cause it to fail.

Comment: +1: That's also a problem, but probably wouldn't lead to the 'usage' error.  A related issue is that the output file is `bessToWss` rather than being in a sub-directory as implied by the rule (unless `$(TARGET_DIR)` is the current directory).

Comment: well, `$INTFOBJS` is composed of 2 other vars put together (I didn't include them in my question though). One is a .o file and the other var is a list of 2 .c files. I wonder if the mix up of .o and .c files could result in the error... ? Good guess.

Comment: @Adrian: No; the C compiler will handle a mix of C and object files (and assembler files, if you're so inclined) with aplomb.  I'm fairly sure the trouble is one of the options you have specified.  I'd expect the compiler (linker) to complain about 'no object files specified' or '`undefined symbol '_main'`' or something similar if the files list was an issue.